# Accessing Row of Data Returned by VBA Search

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter a worksheet of data by Company Name. When I AutoFilter using Criteria1 "name", let's say the company I'm searching for is Google, I will get a number of rows of data back (for argument's sake, say I get 6 rows back). When I get these 6 rows of data back, I need to access each row individually, and copy that row (pasting in another sheet). However, I can't use the .Rows() element because the row numbers are not in order; one row may be Row 6, another Row 37, another Row 1234, etc.. This is my filtering method, just in case anyone needed to see it:

```
Sheets("Weekly").Range("$A$1:$A$473").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=name
```

How can I access each filtered row's data without knowing the row number of it? Or how can I access that row number?

Comment: If you just copy the range it will only copy visible rows by default. (You can also explicitly copy using `Specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: I don't want to include the Column Titles row. How can I copy the range of returned values only? (Sorry, still kind of new to VBA)

Comment: Copy `Range("A2:A473")` instead. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a typical way:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim Name as string, r as Range, k as Long
    Name = "Google"
    Sheets("Weekly").Range("$A$1:$A$473").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Name

    k = 1
    For Each r In Sheets("Weekly").Range("$A$1:$A$473")
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            r.EntireRow.Cells.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & k)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Is r just an arbitrary name for a row in this example, or is it implicitly recognized by VBA? Also, after "r.EntireRow.Cells.Copy" where you have "Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & k), is that the part of code pasting it in Sheet 2?

Comment: @UMich_2017 - you'll need to declare `r`.  Yes, it's an arbitrary name, NOT implicitly recognized.  And yes, that second part is pasting into Sheet2.   There are a few ways to copy/paste in VBA, the way Gary's Student did it is to just put the destination right after `.Copy` instead of using a new line.

Comment: @UMich_2017  In my code **r** is an undeclared *Range* Object, a single cell in the **A** column.......You are correct about the *Sheet2* part, it is the paste destination.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest filtering and then looping through all of the visible cells.  For example, consider the following:

```
Sub Add_Bs()
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim i As Integer

    sum = 0
    If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode Then
        Sheet1.ShowAllData
    End If

    Sheet1.Range("A1:C10").AutoFilter 2, "B"
    For i = 2 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.count
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            sum = sum + Sheet1.Cells(i, 3)
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print sum
End Sub
```

Let's assume that my worksheet looks like this:

[image: Sheet1]

The above code will filter so that only rows where column B contains "B" are shown.  It first checks to see if a filter is already on, and if so, turns it off.  Then it filters by your criteria.  It then loops through all of the rows, and only applies to the non-hidden rows.  Thus, the output in the Immediate window is 5.

2 Notes: First, this will work for most situations.  If you have an enormous spreadsheet, the loop will take a little longer, and there are more robust ways of only looping through the shown cells, but they are slightly more complicated.  Also note that the AutoFilter command assumes that the first row contains column headers.